# Routing error using Devise on Rails 3.0.9

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes, devise

I followed this: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise

```
gem install devise
rails generate devise:install
rails generate devise User
rails generate devise:views
```

Added in config/environments/development.rb

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'localhost:3000' }
```

Added in app/views/layouts/application.html.erb

```
<p class="notice"><%= notice %></p>
<p class="alert"><%= alert %></p>
```

routes.rb :

```
  devise_for :users
  resources :posts
  match "posts/:id/categ" => "posts#categ"
  match "posts/:id/tag_posts" => "posts#tag_posts"
  match "posts/searcharchive" => "posts#searcharchive"
  resources :categories
  resources :comments
  resources :countpages
  root :to => "posts#index"
```

user.rb :

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me
end
```

After http://0.0.0.0:3000/users/sign_in  i got error :

```
 ActionController::RoutingError in Devise/sessions#new

Showing app/views/layouts/application.html.erb where line #25 raised:

No route matches {:controller=>"devise/posts"}

Extracted source (around line #25):

22: 
23:         <div id="header">
24:             <h1>
25:                 <%= link_to 'Home', :controller=>'posts', :action=>'index' %>
26:                 <%= link_to 'Add Post', :controller=>'posts', :action=>'new' %>
27:                 <%= link_to 'Add Category', :controller=>'categories', :action=>'new' %>
28:                 <%= link_to 'Display ategories', :controller=>'categories', :action=>'index' %>
```

app/vies/layouts/application.html.erb :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Railsecommerce</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag :all %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag :defaults %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tag %>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
       <p class="notice"><%= notice %></p>
       <p class="alert"><%= alert %></p>
       <div id="nav_menu">
       <h1>
        <% if user_signed_in? %>
          <%= link_to('Logout', destroy_user_session_path, :method => 'delete') %>
        <% else %>
          <%= link_to('Login', new_user_session_path)  %>
        <% end %>
        </h1>
       </div>

        <div id="header">
            <h1>
                <%= link_to 'Home', :controller=>'posts', :action=>'index' %>
                <%= link_to 'Add Post', :controller=>'posts', :action=>'new' %>
                <%= link_to 'Add Category', :controller=>'categories', :action=>'new' %>
                <%= link_to 'Display ategories', :controller=>'categories', :action=>'index' %>             
            </h1>
        </div>
        <div id="content">
            <%= render :partial => "rightsidediv" %>
        </div>
        <div id="footer">
            <%= "user1@Copyright 2011" %>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Full trace :

```
actionpack (3.0.9) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:425:in `raise_routing_error'
actionpack (3.0.9) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:407:in `rescue in generate'
actionpack (3.0.9) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:396:in `generate'
actionpack (3.0.9) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:454:in `generate'
actionpack (3.0.9) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:482:in `url_for'
actionpack (3.0.9) lib/action_dispatch/routing/url_for.rb:131:in `url_for'
actionpack (3.0.9) lib/action_view/helpers/url_helper.rb:99:in `url_for'
actionpack (3.0.9) lib/action_view/helpers/url_helper.rb:236:in `link_to'
app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:25:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb__426984258_80460110__468457409'
actionpack (3.0.9) lib/action_view/template.rb:135:in `block in render'
activesupport (3.0.9) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:54:in `instrument'
actionpack (3.0.9) lib/action_view/template.rb:127:in `render'
actionpack (3.0.9) lib/action_view/render/layouts.rb:80:in `_render_layout'
actionpack (3.0.9) lib/action_view/render/rendering.rb:62:in `block in _render_template'
activesupport (3.0.9) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:52:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (3.0.9) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:21:in `instrument'
activesupport (3.0.9) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:52:in `instrument'
actionpack (3.0.9) lib/action_view/render/rendering.rb:56:in `_render_template'
actionpack (3.0.9) lib/action_view/render/rendering.rb:26:in `render'
actionpack (3.0.9) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:115:in `_render_template'
actionpack (3.0.9) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:109:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (3.0.9) lib/action_controller/metal/renderers.rb:47:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (3.0.9) lib/action_controller/metal/compatibility.rb:55:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (3.0.9) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:102:in `render_to_string'
actionpack (3.0.9) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:93:in `render'
actionpack (3.0.9) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:17:in `render'
actionpack (3.0.9) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:40:in `block (2 levels) in render'
activesupport (3.0.9) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:5:in `block in ms'
/home/user1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/1.9.1/benchmark.rb:309:in `realtime'
activesupport (3.0.9) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:5:in `ms'
actionpack (3.0.9) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:40:in `block in render'
actionpack (3.0.9) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:78:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
activerecord (3.0.9) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:15:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
actionpack (3.0.9) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:39:in `render'
devise (1.4.2) lib/devise/controllers/scoped_views.rb:28:in `render_with_scope'
devise (1.4.2) app/controllers/devise/sessions_controller.rb:9:in `block in new'
actionpack (3.0.9) lib/action_controller/metal/responder.rb:190:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.9) lib/action_controller/metal/responder.rb:190:in `default_render'
actionpack (3.0.9) lib/action_controller/metal/responder.rb:126:in `to_html'
actionpack (3.0.9) lib/action_controller/metal/responder.rb:119:in `respond'
actionpack (3.0.9) lib/action_controller/metal/responder.rb:112:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.9) lib/action_controller/metal/mime_responds.rb:232:in `respond_with'
devise (1.4.2) lib/devise/controllers/internal_helpers.rb:142:in `respond_with_navigational'
devise (1.4.2) app/controllers/devise/sessions_controller.rb:9:in `new'
actionpack (3.0.9) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
actionpack (3.0.9) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:150:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.0.9) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:11:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.0.9) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:18:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (3.0.9) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:451:in `_run__266949910__process_action__1020298917__callbacks'
activesupport (3.0.9) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:410:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
activesupport (3.0.9) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:94:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (3.0.9) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.0.9) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (3.0.9) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:52:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (3.0.9) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:21:in `instrument'
activesupport (3.0.9) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:52:in `instrument'
actionpack (3.0.9) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.0.9) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:17:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.0.9) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:119:in `process'
actionpack (3.0.9) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:41:in `process'
actionpack (3.0.9) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:138:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.0.9) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:14:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.0.9) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:178:in `block in action'
actionpack (3.0.9) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:62:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.9) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:62:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.0.9) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.9) lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:39:in `call'
rack-mount (0.6.14) lib/rack/mount/route_set.rb:148:in `block in call'
rack-mount (0.6.14) lib/rack/mount/code_generation.rb:93:in `block in recognize'
rack-mount (0.6.14) lib/rack/mount/code_generation.rb:68:in `optimized_each'
rack-mount (0.6.14) lib/rack/mount/code_generation.rb:92:in `recognize'
rack-mount (0.6.14) lib/rack/mount/route_set.rb:139:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.9) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:493:in `call'
warden (1.0.4) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
warden (1.0.4) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
warden (1.0.4) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.9) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/best_standards_support.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.9) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/head.rb:14:in `call'
rack (1.2.3) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:24:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.9) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:21:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.9) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:182:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.9) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/session/abstract_store.rb:149:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.9) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:302:in `call'
activerecord (3.0.9) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:32:in `block in call'
activerecord (3.0.9) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb:28:in `cache'
activerecord (3.0.9) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:12:in `cache'
activerecord (3.0.9) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:31:in `call'
activerecord (3.0.9) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:354:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.9) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:46:in `block in call'
activesupport (3.0.9) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:416:in `_run_call_callbacks'
actionpack (3.0.9) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:44:in `call'
rack (1.2.3) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:107:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.9) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:48:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.9) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:47:in `call'
railties (3.0.9) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:13:in `call'
rack (1.2.3) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
activesupport (3.0.9) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
rack (1.2.3) lib/rack/lock.rb:11:in `block in call'
<internal:prelude>:10:in `synchronize'
rack (1.2.3) lib/rack/lock.rb:11:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.9) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:30:in `call'
railties (3.0.9) lib/rails/application.rb:168:in `call'
railties (3.0.9) lib/rails/application.rb:77:in `method_missing'
railties (3.0.9) lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:14:in `call'
rack (1.2.3) lib/rack/content_length.rb:13:in `call'
rack (1.2.3) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:52:in `service'
/home/user1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:111:in `service'
/home/user1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:70:in `run'
/home/user1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:183:in `block in start_thread'
```

rake routes :

```
        new_user_session GET    /users/sign_in(.:format)       {:action=>"new", :controller=>"devise/sessions"}
            user_session POST   /users/sign_in(.:format)       {:action=>"create", :controller=>"devise/sessions"}
    destroy_user_session DELETE /users/sign_out(.:format)      {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"devise/sessions"}
           user_password POST   /users/password(.:format)      {:action=>"create", :controller=>"devise/passwords"}
       new_user_password GET    /users/password/new(.:format)  {:action=>"new", :controller=>"devise/passwords"}
      edit_user_password GET    /users/password/edit(.:format) {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"devise/passwords"}
                         PUT    /users/password(.:format)      {:action=>"update", :controller=>"devise/passwords"}
cancel_user_registration GET    /users/cancel(.:format)        {:action=>"cancel", :controller=>"devise/registrations"}
       user_registration POST   /users(.:format)               {:action=>"create", :controller=>"devise/registrations"}
   new_user_registration GET    /users/sign_up(.:format)       {:action=>"new", :controller=>"devise/registrations"}
  edit_user_registration GET    /users/edit(.:format)          {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"devise/registrations"}
                         PUT    /users(.:format)               {:action=>"update", :controller=>"devise/registrations"}
                         DELETE /users(.:format)               {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"devise/registrations"}
                   posts GET    /posts(.:format)               {:action=>"index", :controller=>"posts"}
                         POST   /posts(.:format)               {:action=>"create", :controller=>"posts"}
                new_post GET    /posts/new(.:format)           {:action=>"new", :controller=>"posts"}
               edit_post GET    /posts/:id/edit(.:format)      {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"posts"}
                    post GET    /posts/:id(.:format)           {:action=>"show", :controller=>"posts"}
                         PUT    /posts/:id(.:format)           {:action=>"update", :controller=>"posts"}
                         DELETE /posts/:id(.:format)           {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"posts"}
                                /posts/:id/categ(.:format)     {:controller=>"posts", :action=>"categ"}
                                /posts/:id/tag_posts(.:format) {:controller=>"posts", :action=>"tag_posts"}
     posts_searcharchive        /posts/searcharchive(.:format) {:controller=>"posts", :action=>"searcharchive"}
              categories GET    /categories(.:format)          {:action=>"index", :controller=>"categories"}
                         POST   /categories(.:format)          {:action=>"create", :controller=>"categories"}
            new_category GET    /categories/new(.:format)      {:action=>"new", :controller=>"categories"}
           edit_category GET    /categories/:id/edit(.:format) {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"categories"}
                category GET    /categories/:id(.:format)      {:action=>"show", :controller=>"categories"}
                         PUT    /categories/:id(.:format)      {:action=>"update", :controller=>"categories"}
                         DELETE /categories/:id(.:format)      {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"categories"}
                comments GET    /comments(.:format)            {:action=>"index", :controller=>"comments"}
                         POST   /comments(.:format)            {:action=>"create", :controller=>"comments"}
             new_comment GET    /comments/new(.:format)        {:action=>"new", :controller=>"comments"}
            edit_comment GET    /comments/:id/edit(.:format)   {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"comments"}
                 comment GET    /comments/:id(.:format)        {:action=>"show", :controller=>"comments"}
                         PUT    /comments/:id(.:format)        {:action=>"update", :controller=>"comments"}
                         DELETE /comments/:id(.:format)        {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"comments"}
              countpages GET    /countpages(.:format)          {:action=>"index", :controller=>"countpages"}
                         POST   /countpages(.:format)          {:action=>"create", :controller=>"countpages"}
           new_countpage GET    /countpages/new(.:format)      {:action=>"new", :controller=>"countpages"}
          edit_countpage GET    /countpages/:id/edit(.:format) {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"countpages"}
               countpage GET    /countpages/:id(.:format)      {:action=>"show", :controller=>"countpages"}
                         PUT    /countpages/:id(.:format)      {:action=>"update", :controller=>"countpages"}
                         DELETE /countpages/:id(.:format)      {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"countpages"}
                    root        /(.:format)                    {:controller=>"posts", :action=>"index"}
```

Comment: So why is this error ?  ActionController::RoutingError in Devise/sessions#new

Answer (score 2):

Did you try using named routes instead. Replace the following lines in application.html.erb

```
<div id="header">
   <h1>
        <%= link_to 'Home', posts_path %>
        <%= link_to 'Add Post', new_post_path %>
        <%= link_to 'Add Category', new_category_path %>
        <%= link_to 'Display Categories', categories_path %>             
   </h1>
</div>
```

Comment: If i use those lines it works, but why would i use those ? What's wrong with the previous syntax ? I want to use the previours format of link_to ,                 <%= link_to 'Add Post', :controller=>'posts', :action=>'new' %>

Comment: You should look at lib/devise/controllers/scoped_views.rb as part of the devise gem. The url users/sign_in will render the sessions/new.html.erb which is present inside the "devise" scope. Hence, when you use the resource options (:controller, :action) instead of named routes for link_to, it will use the current scope as prefix to the controller